# How to clone WordPress theme from github

Tags: wordpress, git, github, wordpress-theming

I've been developing a wordpress theme on a dev site, and all along I've been pushing it to github. It's now ready to be deployed to my live site, but I'm not sure how to do that.

What I've tried so far (that didn't work) is creating an empty `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/` directory on my live site, and I `cd` into it. Then I use `git clone git@github.com:path/to/my-theme.git` but that creates another directory inside of my my-theme/ directory with all of the theme files inside of it. To clarify, that now creates:

`/wp-content/themes/my-theme/my-theme/[all theme files here]`

But I just want the files from the github repo to be placed directly into the original empty my-theme directory that I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `git clone <repo> .` -- you can specify the directory as the last argument.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! One quick follow up question: how would I update this clone when a new version is pushed to github from the dev site?

Comment: simply `cd` inside and do `git pull`. If you want more control you can `git fetch` to get the updated version from dev which will not modify the checked-out working copy and then `git merge` when you're happy. `git pull` is basically the same as `git fetch && git merge`

Comment: Once again I thank you for the quick and accurate answer. `git pull` did exactly what I was looking for.